# Passing a list of classes to a template

Tags: c++

I want to make a pipeline, where I'd specify a few processing classes 
as template arguments and the template would pass data between them etc.

So I've kinda got it working with VC/IntelC, but not clang/gcc.
How do I fix this code and make it portable?

Here you can see that microsoft compilers understand it: https://godbolt.org/g/0UBnTU

But with gcc/clang I'm getting "explicit specialization in non-namespace scope",
or "function template partial specialization is not allowed" if I try a different approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct proc1 { int x[1]; };
struct proc2 { int x[2]; };
struct proc3 { int x[3]; };
struct proc4 { int x[4]; };

template< int N > struct S1;
template<> struct S1<0> { typedef proc1 t; };
template<> struct S1<1> { typedef proc2 t; };
template<> struct S1<2> { typedef proc3 t; };
template<> struct S1<3> { typedef proc4 t; };

template< int _N, template<int i> class Sx > 
struct S2 {
  enum{ N=_N };

  void* tbl[N];

  template< typename TT > struct print {
    template< typename Self >
    static void x( Self* This, int ii ) {
      This->tbl[ii] = new TT;
      printf( "sizeof(Sx<%i>)=%i sizeof(Self)=%i\n", ii, int(sizeof(TT)), int(sizeof(Self)) );
    }
  };

  template< class Self, template<typename TT> class func >
  struct for_all {
    template< int ii > static void x( Self* This ) {
      func< typename Sx<ii>::t >::x(This,ii);
      x<ii+1>(This);
    }
    template<> static void x<N>( Self* This ) {}
  };

  void test( void ) {
    printf( "N=%i\n", N );
    for_all<S2,print>::x<0>(this);
  }

};

S2<4,S1> X;

int main( ) {
  X.test();
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what variadic parameter packs are for?

Comment: But this is C++98 and it works, why make it less compatible? But I'd appreciable a variadic solution too.

Comment: There is no function template specialization, so your `template <> static void x<N>` overload is invalid, which is why your compiler should complain. Use overloading with `std::integral_constant` or like to achieve what you want. Or if you have c++11 support, use variadic templates.

Comment: I tried using plain class templates there, but then VC can't compile it, while clang/gcc can. I even tried VS2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code is invalid is because there are no function template specialization in C++, therefore the `template <> static void x<N>(Self* This){}` is invalid.

What you *can* do is overloading:

```
template <int I>
struct integer_constant {};

template <int I>
void foo(integer_constant<I>)
{
    std::cout << I << '\n';
    foo(integer_constant<I - 1>());
}

void foo(integer_constant<0>)
{
    std::cout << 0 << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    foo(integer_constant<5>());
}
```

In your case, it looks like this:

```
template< class Self, template<typename TT> class func >
struct for_all {
    template< int ii > static void x( Self* This, integer_constant<ii> ) {
        func< typename Sx<ii>::t >::x(This,ii);
        x(This, integer_constant<ii + 1>());
    }
    static void x( Self* This, integer_constant<N> ) {}
};
```

I've rolled my own `integer_constant` for this example since you can't have C++11, but if you can, you should use something standard like [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant)

Comment: Seems like interesting idea, I'd check it.

Comment: Same case: works in VC/IntelC, doesn't in gcc/clang - https://godbolt.org/g/a6AO1q

Comment: Your statement that there is no function specialization isn't valid. One just cannot use full template specialization inside template class...

Comment: Gcc/clang says  "explicit specialization in non-namespace scope" is not allowed.

Comment: And clang and gcc are right. Full function template specialization is perfectly valid in namespace scope.